# Slide and fade images using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple homepage with two main images side by side and a third button image centered on top of them as an enter button. Is it possible to have the 2 main images slide off screen, one to the left and one to the right and have the enter button fade away when clicked on, to reveal a web page underneath?

I couldn't find anything online and I'm a newbie too, any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Yup, that is possible. Please start, and if you have any issues, post them here and you will get help if you provide a complete example showing the issue.

Comment: Please post your relevant attempt, or possibly a jsfiddle.net. Its hard to picture what you want with only a text description.

Comment: [Yes, it's possible.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery animate - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('.left').animate({"margin-left":-1000});
    $('.right').animate({"margin-right":-1000},function(){
        $this.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This isn't productive or helpful either, because he doesn't know what this is.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r285t/1/

Comment: It's a good start that actually provides some guidance...

Comment: it's duplicating boilerplate code that's written a million places better already, with the same relevant link as before.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I kind of understand it, I'll figure it out! Much appreciated

Comment: I'm sure you'll get it. Good luck in your travels, David.